# How to maximize Zergling/Roach army by the 12-minute-mark?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I know it's possible to reach 200 supply in under 12 minutes playing as Zerg.

Assumptions:

- not attacked by opponent
- Queen injects larvae on time

How can I efficiently and quickly create a max army of Zerlings and Roaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Stephano is famous for doing the 12 minute roach max, i would suggest watching his stream and trying to copy his play. He perfected that strategy to a point where 12 minute max is quite late for him (11:04 with harass is his record).

Also, you might want to check out this TeamLiquid Thread for more in-depth info on how he does it and how to get there:
http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=324733

Answer (score 4):

Assuming perfect play and only drone production, its about 11:30, Ret did under 12 minutes in a professional game against a FFE Protoss, so its actually a useful strategy to know, because being able to max out fast puts pressure on your opponent.

As for how its done:

Some variation of
http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/3_Hatch_Before_Gas_(vs._Protoss)

The jist is to drone up to about 50 drones, whilst building up gas, then on 3 bases pump roaches.

Injects need to correct to the millisecond.
Minerals should be glued at 0.
Take a few attempts to streamline the build, when to take the third and when move to 6 gas

Comment: Link goes to an empty page?

Comment: fixed the broken link

Answer (score 2):

It's doable with a very economy based opening. So you go to three bases very quickly and just drone up heavily. Don't take any gases until about 50 supply.

You should invest into queens instead of lings to hold off early (light) aggression, because they don't cost larva. The key is not to get supply-blocked and always hit your larva-injects. If you do that, it's certainly possible (albeit hard if you get distracted) to max out on roaches at around 12 minutes.